# Using the function Placed in BarChart

Tags: charts

I have this BarChart:

```
BarChart[
  {{33/36, 3/36}, {27/36, 8/36, 1/36}, {13/36, 10/36, 2/36, 1/36, 1/36, 4/36, 1/36, 1/36}},
  ChartLabels -> 
    {{Style["Набор 1", Black, Bold, FontSize -> 24],
      Style["Set 2", Black, Bold, FontSize -> 24],
      Style["Set 3", Black, Bold, FontSize -> 24]},
      Placed[
        {Style["node 4", FontSize -> 18, White],
         Style["node 9", FontSize -> 18, White],
         Style["node 7", FontSize -> 18, White],
         Style["node 5", FontSize -> 18, White],
         Style["node 6", FontSize -> 18, White],
         Style["node 10", FontSize -> 18, White],
         Style["node 11", FontSize -> 18, White],
         Style["node 13", FontSize -> 18, White]},
        Center,
        Rotate[#, 0 Degree] &]},
  ChartStyle -> 
    {GrayLevel[0.1], GrayLevel[0.2], GrayLevel[0.25], 
     GrayLevel[0.3], GrayLevel[0.35], GrayLevel[0.4], GrayLevel[0.45], 
     GrayLevel[0.5]},
  ChartLayout -> "Stacked",
  ImageSize -> 1100,
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 24],
  BarSpacing -> {0, 1.2}]
```

[image]

It can be noted that stack is formed from the min bar length to the max one but only in first two columns. I would like to locate nodes in Set 3 in descending order (from bottom to top), but it seems to me that I can't do that because I've already used `Placed` inappropriately in my case, or I just don't know the appropriate function.

Could someone help me or give some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = {{33/36, 3/36}, {27/36, 8/36, 1/36}, {13/36, 10/36, 2/36, 1/36, 1/36, 
  4/36, 1/36, 1/36}}; 
labels = Style[#, FontSize -> 18, White] & /@ {"node 4", "node 9", "node 7", 
   "node 5", "node 6", "node 10", "node 11", "node 13"};
grouplabels = Style[#, Black, Bold, FontSize -> 24] & /@ {"Набор 1", "Set 2", "Set 3"};
labeleddata = Labeled[##, Axis] & @@@ Transpose[{SortBy[-First[#] &] /@ 
 (MapIndexed[Labeled[#, labels[[#2[[1]]]], Center] &, #] & /@ data), grouplabels}];

BarChart[labeleddata, 
 ChartStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.1], GrayLevel[0.2], GrayLevel[0.25], 
   GrayLevel[0.3], GrayLevel[0.35], GrayLevel[0.4], GrayLevel[0.45], 
   GrayLevel[0.5]}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ImageSize -> 900, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 24], BarSpacing -> {0, 1.2}]
```

[image]